# How to initialize Bootstrap tooltip in custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to move my tooltip initialization out of jQuery and into the link function of a custom directive. The HTML is fairly simple:

```
<p data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Players live: {{players.loggedIn}}' id='login-count'>
```

Current jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login-count').tooltip();
});
```

What I'm attempting to do in my custom directive:

```
function link(scope, element) {
  var loginCount = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('#login-count'));
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    loginCount.tooltip();
  });
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: loginCount.tooltip is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your custom directive should be like this

```
angular.module('yourAppName') .directive('mytooltip', function() {
'use strict';

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el) {
        $(el).tooltip();
    }
};
});
```

and then i html you can add it like:

```
<p data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' 
title='Players live: {{players.loggedIn}}' id='login-count' mytooltip>
```

also keep in mind to include jquery before angular.js because otherwise Angular will load and use jqlite.

In any case I would rather go with Angular tooltips like http://720kb.github.io/angular-tooltips or even better bootstrap for angular http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

Comment: The el in the directive function is likely already decorated with jquery lite functions. Uncertain if the tooltip extension will be included. There is angular-bootstrap project that will likely be helpful to ensure your desired bootstrap-based functions are available.

Comment: Ended up using the Angular-UI Bootstrap tooltips.